# move singlechildscroll view back to top position after refresh in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

**whenever I tap on any of the options of the given 4 buttons, my new data loads in the text and in the 4 option fields.
but the scroll view doesn't come back to its normal position, instead, it remains down, at what position I had left it, previously.
so how to get singlechildscrollview back to its original form after every refresh?**

```
 Expanded(
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            margin:EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0,bottom: 50) ,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xFFf2f2f2),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight:  Radius.circular(40),topLeft:Radius.circular(40) ),

            ),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              child: Container(
                height: 800,
                child: (
                Column(

                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,

                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50,left: 20,right: 20),
                    child: Text(question.replaceAll("\\n", "\n"),style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 18),),
                  ),

                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  optionButton(text: option1),
                  SizedBox(height: 30),
                  optionButton(text: option2),
                  SizedBox(height: 30),
                  optionButton(text: option1),
                  SizedBox(height: 30),
                  optionButton(text: option2),
                  SizedBox(height: 30),
                  Spacer(),




                Column(
                  children: [
                  Text("TOTAL"),
                    Container(
                        width: MediaQuery. of(context). size. width,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        child:
                        Center(child: Text(score.toString(),)),),
SizedBox(height: 20)
                ],),
                ],
                )

                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I'm not sure what `optionButton` looks like, you'll probably need this first above your build method:

```
ScrollController scrollController = new ScrollController();
```

Then if your `optionButton` is within the same class, call this within your button function `onTap(){} or onPressed(){}` :

```
scrollController.jumpTo(0.0);
```

Make sure to add the controller to `SingleChildScrollView`

If `optionButton` is from a different class, then I'll have to change my answer.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: i think that is the way , i vote it up , there is another way which you can animate it to the top you should put it in ontap or onChanged function`_scrollController.animateTo(0, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn);`

Comment: Thanks a lot, both of the methods worked. much appreciated I have also voted up, but since I have less than 15 reputations, my vote will not count as of now.